# http request in Angular in which I pass an array

Tags: angular, http, url, get, httprequest

the code I use to make the get request is as follows:

```
options: any;
getWithParameters(url: string, parameters: any): Observable<any> {
    this.options.params = this.getParameters(parameters); 
    console.log(this.options);
    this.loaderService.show();
    return this.http
        .get(url, this.options)
        .map(result => {
            return this.extractData(result);
        })
        .catch(ex => {
            return this.errorService.handleError(ex, this.errorService);
        }).finally(() => {
            this.options.params = {};
            this.loaderService.hide();
        });
}

getParameters(params: any): HttpParams {
    let parameters = new HttpParams();
    for (const key in params) {
        if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            const val = params[key];
            parameters = parameters.append(key, val);
        }
    }
    return parameters;
}
```

`parameters` is a json. When `parameters` only contain simple variables like:

- CommercialName : ""
- DraftNumber : ""
- IdApplication : null

it work and the request is 
`http://localhost:53035/Api/OfferApi/GetDraftList&IdApplication=null&CommercialName=&DraftNumber=`

But when `parameters`contain an array like:

- CommercialName:""
- DraftNumber:""
- IdApplication: ["10", "9"]

it does not work and the request is 
`http://localhost:53035/Api/OfferApi/GetDraftList&IdApplication=10,9&CommercialName=&DraftNumber=`

the request should be made this way to work
`http://localhost:53035/Api/OfferApi/GetDraftList&IdApplication[]=10&IdApplication[]=9&CommercialName=&DraftNumber=`

does anyone have ideas to print the request correctly?
Thanks

Comment: What you are getting is the correct syntax. Maybe you should change your backend instead, to accept several values into the URL params ?

Comment: It totally depends on what you have behind on the backend. This is correct syntax, as is the was you want it to have. your backend has to deal with it after all. What kind of backend do you use?

Comment: ah, got it, thank you very much.
I use a back end in asp.net whit mvc. but it was not programmed by me, now I ask at developer.
In case, be sure there is no way to get the syntax like this `IdApplication[]=10&IdApplication[]=9`?

Comment: There are certainly are ways to do it, but it's cumbersome. I just tried it out myself, and in my case angular sends the array like this `IdApplication=9&IdApplication=10` means you could just change the propertyname to include the []. Which doesn't seem to be nice for me tho.

Comment: perfect, thank you, very kind

Comment: btw, here's a little example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gitter-2qgujj tested in chrome, it sends each array element seperately. I don't know what causes your problem tho.

Answer (score -1):

First thing you can add an array []

`getWithParameters(url: string, parameters: any[]): Observable<any> {}`

Second thing is you can create a model Object.

`getWithParameters(url: string, parameters: any[]): Observable<ModelObject> {}`

Thanks.